# how to use user defined function with two arguments in groupby function in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

my data is like this:

```
x1  x2  var1  var2
0   1   1     1 
0   0   2     2
0   0   1     3
1   0   3     3
```

I defined a function for calculating the weighted mean as-

```
def W_M(x,w):
    y1=w.div(w.sum())
    m=x*y1.div(y1.sum())
    m=m.sum()
    return(m)
```

here I want to calculate W_M for var1 and using var2 as weight when data grouped by 'by' object.

```
by=['x1','x2']
df.groupby(by,as_index=False).agg({var1: lambda x: x.W_M(var1,var2)})
```

I don't know above groupby code is correct or not..but i tried.

And i want output as shown below:

```
x1 x2 var1 var2
0   1   1     1
0   0   1     5
1   0   1     3
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Really hard for us to tell what's wrong without knowing which error is raised and how the data is like

Comment: now i added sample data to it.

Comment: and it produces the following error.::   'Series' object has no attribute 'W_M'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.average` and for new column [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = data.groupby(['x1','x2']).apply(lambda x: np.average(x['var1'], weights=x['var2']))
print (s)
x1  x2
0   0     1.4
    1     1.0
1   0     3.0
dtype: float64

result = data.drop('var1', axis=1).join(s.rename('var1'), on=['x1','x2'])
#if necessary change ordering of columns
result = result[['x1','x2','var1','var2']]
print (result)
   x1  x2  var1  var2
0   0   1   1.0     1
1   0   0   1.4     2
2   0   0   1.4     3
3   1   0   3.0     3
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But i tried apply function. It doesn't give me the output as i mentioned in question.

Comment: No..sorry to say you  again i clearly mentioned my expected outpt in my question. That weighted values comes under var1 only..I don't want to create extra object for that...

Comment: we are aggregating data by x1 and x2  then we are doing some operations and here x1 and x2 are  in same level then we can add them.

Comment: W_M function returns W_mean value only. But by using groupby we need to apply that function to each group in the dataset and store that information in var1 object in the grouped data. did you get my point?

Comment: @neeraja - Now understand, my main problem was you want different output format like you write in question `And i want output as shown below:`, check edited answer for solution.

Comment: sorry, by mistake i  did that.

Comment: @neeraja - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank god, after so many trails, finally i got a solution.
below i mentioned  the code for generating the expected output.

```
out=data.groupby(['x1','x2'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: np.average(x['var1'], 
weights=x['var2']))
bn=pd.DataFrame(out)
bn.reset_index(inplace=True)
bn=bn.rename(columns={0:'var1'})
result = pd.merge(bn,
                  data[['x1','x2','var2']],
                  on=['x1','x2'], 
                  how='left')
```